# How do I express "to survive" in a more metaphorical sense?

Tags: words, translation

My friend published a multi-part video on Facebook. I wanted to comment "I survived for only one episode", as in "It was so bad I couldn't keep watching after just one episode", but I wasn't sure which word would fit for "survived".  (I'm also not really sure this is a metaphorical usage.)

I thought about:

> 1話だけ残った
>
> 1話だけ生き残った

But, I think both sound really, really ridiculous.

Comment: Both mean “Only one episode survived,” and therefore they do not convey the intended meaning.  I am not sure if 生き残る is ever used for the meaning stated in the question.

Comment: Maybe you can use「耐える」「我慢する」?　・・・ (１話だけ見たけど、これ以上耐えられない... 見てみたけど、１話が限界...　ダメだ、１話でギブ（アップ）... is my honest opinion...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, both are bad.

"1話だけ残った" would be "it's down to the [last] one episode", and thus it's actually the opposite of what you want to convey.

"1話だけ生き残った" would mean "all but one episode were lost", and again it doesn't make sense (but given the context, it'll probably be understood.)

If I were you, I'd go with 一話で力尽きた

Comment: I agree.  As a general rule of thumb, when a sentence containing “only” is difficult to translate into Japanese, it is often a good idea to rewrite it from the opposite side, such as rewriting “I survived for only…” to “I stopped watching after….”